# Looping over multiple json arrays with Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a large JSON file structured like the following which I'm trying to loop over in Angular:

```
    {
       "subject1":[
          {
             "title":"titlehere",
             "info":"infohere."
          }],

       "subject2":[
          {
             "title":"titlehere",
             "info":"infohere."
          }],
       "subject3":[
          {
             "title":"titlehere",
             "info":"infohere."
          }]
}
```

I want my page to grab the key for each 'category' and then the display the title underneath it. I'm able to get the key to display but I can't seem to figure out how to grab the string for each title. This is what I have in my HTML:

```
            <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in faqs">
            <h3>{{ key }}</h3>
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="#" ng-click="showHide(pageInfo)">{{ value }}</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

I'm not sure what I should be using instead of `{{ value }}` which grabs nothing but the entire JSON file as a string. I tried `{{ value.title }}` and still had no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you know it's "pure JSON"? Have you checked what (typeof value) says?

Comment: I was using that as a way to describe that it's pulling the entire json object as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `{{ value[0].title }}`

your code be

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in faqs">
     <h3>{{ key }}</h3>
     <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="val in value"><a href="#" ng-click="showHide(pageInfo)">{{ val.title }}</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: While this works, that only grabs the first one instead of everything. If there were 100 titles how would I grab all of them?

Comment: Again you loop again towards ul that solve, I update it wait a min

Comment: @JamesIves Updated check

Comment: Works great. Not sure why I didn't think of that! Thank you.

Comment: @JqueryKing: Doesnt the second `ng-repeat` simply loops the entire `ul`?